# How can I connect to Amazon EMR Hive via Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive

I'd like to connect to an AWS EMR Hive instance from Ruby.  I've found https://github.com/forward3d/rbhive, but am not sure if the server address is the same as the Hadoop server address, and also am not sure of the port on which Hive is listening on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AWS EMR Hive this is the way you connect to default version.

```
RBHive.tcli_connect('<AWS-EMR-IP>', 10_000) do |connection|
  connection.fetch('SHOW TABLES')
end
```

And Hive listens to port 10000 for Hive 0.13.1 version. Check this link if you want to connect to different version.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hive-differences.html

Comment: Thanks - but this creates some more questions:
1) when I run that code, I get:
``tcli_connect': undefined method `key?' for 10000:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
 from hivetest.rb:3:in `<main>'`
2) My Hive version is listed as 1.0.0 in the AWS console, and there is no entry for that on.  Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is quiet broad for answering in one go :)

Comment: Here is the new guide for updates version of Hive in AWS http://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-components.html